# Run a MATLAB image processing script on GPU

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gpu

I am working on a script for creating data set based [CEDD](http://savvash.blogspot.com/2013/09/matlab-version-of-cedd-descriptor.html) feature of image. But when i run it, it takes alot of time to accomplish it. I want to run it on gpu so that it can be fast. My code to create the data set is below :

```
for i=1:totalFiles
try
    image = readimage(trainingSet,i);   
catch e
   disp(e);  
end
cedd = CEDD(image);
zerosCount = 0 ;
for j=1:144
    if cedd(j) == 0
        zerosCount=zerosCount + 1;
    end
end
if zerosCount ~= 144
    data(i , :) = cedd;
    labels(i , : ) = trainingSet.Labels(i);
end
d.Value = i/totalFiles(1,1);
d.Message = sprintf('%3.2f "% completed" ',d.Value*100);
end
```

How i can run this code on gpu or i have to convert the CEDD implementation for gpu ?

Answer (score 0):

The basic GPU programming model in MATLAB is that you need the Parallel Computing Toolbox and an NVIDIA GPU that supports CUDA. Given those things, gpuArray is how you perform work on the GPU in MATLAB:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/gpuarray.html

The basic idea is that you construct a gpuArray, which moves data into GPU memory, and then you perform math operations on the newly constructed gpuArray just as you would numeric data. Depending on whether all the functions that CEDD relies on support gupArray, it may be as simple as:

```
cedd = CEDD(gpuArray(image));
```

Comment: no CEDD is simple not relies on gpuArray ... i have to make all the array as gpuArray and it will be ok ?